# Most efficient way to find bidirectional differences between associative arrays

Tags: php, algorithm, filtering, big-o, array-difference

I have a contact array with a set of values which I need to update. I also have a contactChangeLog array that will save the diff between an existing and updated contact. Only the keys which get updated need to be saved to the log. So with 2 contact arrays:

```
$oldContact = array(
        'name' => 'Joeahkd',
        'address' => '123 Masjdhfin',
        'city' => 'Spring',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '90101',
 );

$newContact = array(
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'address' => '123 Main St',
        'city' => 'Springville',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '90101',
);
```

I can use array_diff_assoc()...

```
$existing = array_diff_assoc($oldContact, $newContact);
$update = array_diff_assoc($newContact, $oldContact);

$diff = array('previous' => $existing, 'new' => $update);
print_r($diff);
```

However, I am iterating twice through each array and something I learned about big O notation tells me that isn't right. Is there a more algorithmically efficient way of returning the updated keys and both existing and updated values? The result should be:

```
$previous = array(
        'name' => 'Joeahkd',
        'address' => '123 Masjdhfin',
        'city' => 'Spring'
 );

$updated = array(
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'address' => '123 Main St',
        'city' => 'Springville'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `array_filter`:

```
$updated = array();    
$previous = array_filter($oldContact, function($v, $k) {
    if ($v != $newContact[$k]) {
        $updated[$k] = $newContact[$k];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

`array_filter` will return the keys/values from the input array if the callback function we specify returns true during each key/value iteration and those will be our `$previous`. While we do the checking in the callback function we construct `$updated`.

UPDATE:

Using `array_filter` with `array_intersect_key` even cut the code further:

```
$previous = array_filter($oldContact, function($v, $k) {
    return ($v != $newContact[$k]);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

$updated = array_intersect_key($newContact, $previous);
```

Comment: This is great. More efficient than what I wrote and with an anonymous function, which I hadn't seen that much in the wild in PHP.

Comment: I'm also going to do some simple benchmark testing using microtime() before and after each of these implementations. Have been working with a C++ programmer and discussing the underlying C libraries that the language is using.

Comment: How does `$newContact` magically get into the custom function's scope?  How does `$updated` get out of the custom function's scope?  Did you actually test your advice before posting it?

Comment: @mickmackusa this answer was like 7 years ago so things changed.

Comment: Which php version allowed you to access global variables withing a custom function scope?  Did you test this code back in 2015?  If this answer ever did work, it is certainly misleading researchers now.

Comment: This answer is not implementing bi-directional comparisons anyhow.  It is one way.  Your snippets are iterating `$oldContact` then checking its values against `$newContact`.  It never iterates `$newContact` to check against `$oldContact` data.  It relies on the situational convenience that the two arrays have identical length and keys.  The asker's two `array_diff_assoc()` calls do not suffer the same vulnerability.

Comment: @mickmackusa feel free to edit

Comment: Likewise. @Lukman

Answer (score 0):

The next approach that I would try would be:

```
public function diff($newObj, $oldObj)
{
    $updatedVals = [];
    $previousVals = [];

    foreach ($newObj as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($newObj[$key] !== $oldObj[$key])
        {
                $updatedVals[] = $newObj[$key];
                $previousVals[] = $oldObj[$key];
        }

        return [$newVals, $previousVals];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, just use the edit button left bottom of your question to do that (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28209575/edit), just write something like: `edit:...`

Comment: Thx for your comment. I did actually edit the question at one point. And also admittedly wrote the original question over a couple of days. So when I finally got to posting it, I had already come up with a possible answer. I did think it sort of fit as an answer, but understand your point.

Comment: Ah, if you did figure it out, then it's fine as an answer :D

Comment: This answer is not implementing bi-directional comparisons.  It is one way.  Your snippet is iterating `$newObj` then checking its values against `$oldObj`.  It never iterates `$oldObj` to check against `$newObj` data.  It relies on the situational convenience that the two arrays have identical length and keys.  Your originally used two `array_diff_assoc()` calls do not suffer the same vulnerability.  You'd need to `foreach ($array1 + $array2 as $uniqueKey => $notNeededValue) {` with your snippet.  Your `return` 's first element is using the wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

I almost agree with @shotdsheriff's approach but it has a typo in it, it returns the two arrays after destroying the associative relationships, and it is important to be aware of a potential fringe case where a key is found in one array but not the other.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BXCPR))

```
$oldContact = array(
        'name' => 'Joeahkd',
        'address' => '123 Masjdhfin',
        'city' => 'Spring',
        'a-key-only-in-old' => 'foo',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '90101',
 );

$newContact = array(
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'a-key-only-in-new' => 'bar',
        'address' => '123 Main St',
        'city' => 'Springville',
        'state' => 'CA',
        'zip' => '90101',
);

$oldDiff = [];
$newDiff = [];
foreach ($oldContact + $newContact as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($oldContact[$key]) && !isset($newContact[$key])) {
        $oldDiff[$key] = $oldContact[$key];
    } elseif (isset($newContact[$key]) && !isset($oldContact[$key])) {
        $newDiff[$key] = $newContact[$key];
    } elseif ($oldContact[$key] !== $newContact[$key]) {
        $oldDiff[$key] = $oldContact[$key];
        $newDiff[$key] = $newContact[$key];
    }
}

echo "Old Diff: " . var_export($oldDiff, true) . "\n";
echo "New Diff: " . var_export($newDiff, true);
```

Output:

```
Old Diff: array (
  'name' => 'Joeahkd',
  'address' => '123 Masjdhfin',
  'city' => 'Spring',
  'a-key-only-in-old' => 'foo',
)
New Diff: array (
  'name' => 'Joe',
  'address' => '123 Main St',
  'city' => 'Springville',
  'a-key-only-in-new' => 'bar',
)
```

While it may have a lower computational time, I don't find it to more readable than two `array_diff_assoc()` calls and I am not certain that it will always outperform the simple native function calls.

If a project is guaranteed to have two arrays where the length and the keys will be the same, then the array union (`+`) in the `foreach()` can be replaced with just one of the arrays and the conditions relying on `isset()` can be completely removed -- as demonstrated in @shotdsheriff's answer.

Here is my recommended version of @shotdsheriff's answer: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kak49))

```
$oldDiff = [];
$newDiff = [];
foreach ($oldContact as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== $newContact[$key]) {
        $oldDiff[$key] = $value;
        $newDiff[$key] = $newContact[$key];
    }
}
```